# Does "docker swarm leave" sends any kind of SIGNAL to the containers to give them a chance to gracefully shutdown?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I wasn´t able to find an answer to this and simple tests let me think, that docker is killing the containers without any SIGNAL.

**If this is really the case:** How can I remove a node from the swarm gracefully without killing any containers that are currently running?

Comment: The swarm provides a specific network to the containers running on it. So your goal would be to keep a swarm container running correctly *despite* losing network once its node left the swarm?

Comment: @A.B pardon, i don´t understand your comment. i asking about SIGNALs, don´t know what this has anything in common with networking.